# How to extract the file name from a column of paths

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am converting the `.txt` file into `labels.csv` by adding some columns in a data frame. How I can remove **images/0/** from the column contains `images/1/19997.jpg, images/1/19998.jpg images/1/19999.jpg` `/0` is folder name and it varies time to time

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

# Read space-separated columns without header
data = pd.read_csv('/media/cvpr/CM_24/synthtiger/results/gt.txt', sep="\s+", header=None)

# Update columns
data.columns = ['filename', 'words']

# Save to required format
data.to_csv('labels.csv')
```

Comment: If the filename properties is fixed? As in, there is a guarantee that all the image will have .jpg extension and have 5 character name.

Comment: Characters are varies file to file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably more efficient method using slicing (assuming the filename have a fixed properties). But you can use os.path.basename. It will automatically retrieve the valid filename from the path.

```
data['filename_clean'] = data['filename'].apply(os.path.basename)
```

[image: [Result Example] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8znU.png]